# React if statments always results in false condition after state re-render

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-component, react-state

I have this Component in react which will return 'Loading' title, 'Logged in' title or 'Not Logged in' title, depending on the state.

I have made the state so that it updates and changes from 'Loading' to either 'Logged in' or 'Not Logged in' as soon as the `isLoggedIn` promise returns a value of either `true` or `false`.

However, my second If statment is always conditionally proving false, and hence always returning 'Not Logged in' as a title even if the promise returns true (saying the user is logged in).

Here's the code:

```
function UserProfileNavItem(props) {
  const [profiledLoaded, sethasLoaded] = useState(false);
  var isLoggedInLocal = false;
  isLoggedIn().then((res) => {
    if (res) {
      console.log("We are logged in");
      isLoggedInLocal = true;
    }else{
      console.log("We are not logged in");
    }
    sethasLoaded(true);
  });
  if (!profiledLoaded) {
    return (
      <h1>Loading</h1>
    );
  }
  if (!isLoggedInLocal) {
    return (
      <h1>Not Logged In</h1> // THIS IS ALWAYS SENT BACK EVEN IF isLoggedInLocal IS TRUE
);
  } else {
    return (
      <h1>Logged In</h1>  // THIS IS NEVER SENT BACK
    );
  }
}
```

Do not think I need to show my `isLoggedIn` promise, but ask if you need.

(Yes I am new to react)

Comment: What kind of object is 'res'?

Comment: @sunero4 A Boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `var isLoggedInLocal = false;` as state in order to be reactive :

```
function UserProfileNavItem(props) {
  const [profiledLoaded, sethasLoaded] = useState(false);
const [isLoggedInLocal , setIsLoggedInLocal ] = useState(false);
 
  isLoggedIn().then((res) => {
    if (res) {
      console.log("We are logged in");
      setIsLoggedInLocal(true);
    }else{
      console.log("We are not logged in");
    }
    sethasLoaded(true);
  });
  if (!profiledLoaded) {
    return (
      <h1>Loading</h1>
    );
  }
  if (!isLoggedInLocal) {
    return (
      <h1>Not Logged In</h1> IS TRUE
);
  } else {
    return (
      <h1>Logged In</h1> 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did work. I am learning too so just a quick question...anything that needs to be re-rendered/checked again (e.g. if statment) should be in a state?

Comment: you're welcome, Yes any variable that seems important for the component should be a state

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm assuming react-redux would do a similar thing ?

Comment: Yes but for the global state

Comment: Okay, cheers for the clarification. Will approve answer when I can.